# How do I Difference Panel Data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is any easy Python commands or packages that will all allow me to easily add variables to data.frames which are the "difference" or change of over time of those variables.

If my data looked like this:

```
   Day Price    Good
  ---  -------  -- 
1  1     8      apples
2  2    10      apples
3  3     7      apples
4  4    11      apples
5  5    14      apples
6  1    12      oranges
7  2    11      oranges
8  3     9      oranges
9  4    14      oranges
10 5    11      oranges
```

Then after "first differencing" the price variable, my data would look like this.

```
   Day Price    Good P1d
1    1     8  apples  NA
2    2    10  apples   2
3    3     7  apples  -3
4    4    11  apples   4
5    5    14  apples   3
6    1    12 oranges  NA
7    2    11 oranges  -1
8    3     9 oranges  -2
9    4    14 oranges   5
10   5    11 oranges  -3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.groupby()` followed by a `.diff()`:

```
df["P1d"] = df.groupby("Good")["Price"].diff()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Day  Price     Good  P1d
1     1      8   apples  NaN
2     2     10   apples  2.0
3     3      7   apples -3.0
4     4     11   apples  4.0
5     5     14   apples  3.0
6     1     12  oranges  NaN
7     2     11  oranges -1.0
8     3      9  oranges -2.0
9     4     14  oranges  5.0
10    5     11  oranges -3.0
```